# Where can I find good 2D representation of AD&D 1st edition monsters

Tags: monsters, adnd-1e, props, papercraft

I am looking for a good source of images of the Advanced Dungeons & Dragons 1st edition monsters from the Monster Manual, Fiend Folio, and Monster Manual II.

Sure, there are drawings of most of the monsters in the books, but I'm looking for something a little more detailed, maybe even in color.

My players are young (my kids, mostly) and are not very skilled yet at turning a verbal description into "aha, we're being accosted by a xorn!"  I would like a set of pages/cards that I can flip up and hang on the front of the DM screen, and say, "6 of 'these' critters are running toward you, waving their claws and howling."  It will help the game flow a little more smoothly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like this site: [D&D Monster Finder](http://monsterfinder.dndrunde.de)

It's a searchable monster database that helps me find monsters by level, environment, alignment, book (and many more) and it has pictures for almost every monster in every book.

Comment: It looks like it's based on D&D 3.x. Still, there's a lot of overlap between the editions, especially if you want color art.

Comment: I went here and found no images - only database entries of stats.

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer When you do a search, you get a list of results. Clicking on a name in the list expands the entry, and both of the entries I checked (Bhargest and Arrow Hawk) had a View Image link mixed in with the details.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet, actually, is [images.google.com](http://images.google.com/images?hl=en&newwindow=1&gbv=2&tbs=isch:1&q=xorn+dungeons+and+dragons&revid=75864430&sa=X&ei=6pnSTKDoLIPKcZnciYsM&ved=0CCAQ1QIoAA&biw=1678&bih=965). This, combined with [TokenTool](http://www.rptools.net/index.php?page=tokentool) will get you both "pogs" (print it out, cut it out, paste it on thick cardboard).

I use images.google.com for any player avatar I need, and the 4 editions of monsters combined with the imaginations of artists on, for example, deviantart, supply an excellent variety to choose from.

Comment: I did a lightweight version of this.  I wanted to start my first game as a DM, and I hadn't bought any figs yet.  It took me about an hour to grab a bunch of good pictures off of a Google search, toss them on a Word.doc page, print and cut.  I resized the images on the page, with the aspect ratio locked, so the width was 1" or whatever I needed.  Then I copy/pasted a duplicate next to the first one.  I cut out the pairs, close all around except for a 1/2" margin at the bottom.  Then I could fold them back to back, snip the fold at the bottom, and bend up the "base" so they would stand up.

Comment: In one instance, I flipped the image so that a pet Firefoot Fennic could be made to sniff out and "point" to something that I wanted to direct the players attention toward.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the monsters still exist in 3/3.5/4/Pathfinder books.  The stats aren't the same, but the pictures are in color and will be accurate representations.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the 2e Monsterous Compendiums binders had one monster per page, and included good sized pictures of each monster.

Comment: I always laughed at the Invisible Stalker illo.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com) for all my fantasy and sci-fi image needs.  There are tons of searchable images.  Just pay attention to and respect any copyright that the artists may have placed on the works.