# Where can I find miniatures for AD&D monsters?

Tags: monsters, adnd-1e, miniatures

This is a follow-on to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/good-2d-representation-of-dd-monsters).

I am looking **specifically** for only monster, not character or NPC, miniatures from the 1st edition Advanced Dungeons & Dragons Monster Manual, Fiend Folio, and Monster Manual II.  To be used as a supplement/replacement of a monster description when an encounter occurs.

Is there any source out there that would have a fairly complete line of monsters like this?

Comment: Please don't use the "ADND1.0" name in the question title or text. It's a name for the game that isn't used anywhere outside our tag system. "AD&D", "AD&D 1e", and "Advanced Dungeons & Dragons" with or without "1st edition" should be used so that people can find the Q&A from Google. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several sources none of them I would call complete.

The best source for monsters currently is [Otherworld Miniatures](http://www.otherworld.me.uk/). They have a variety of models all inspired or directly related to AD&D monster manual. For example their orcs are pig nosed not the "brutish" type.

While not monsters [Mega Miniatures](http://www.megaminis.com/) has many of the old Grenadier character models. They have monsters as part of their catalog as well.

You could search [Noble Knight Games](http://www.nobleknight.com/) for the originals although that can be pricey.

I also rely on game stores that sells singles for the newer D&D miniatures. There are an amazing variety of models for the same creature and I found several that work well for their AD&D counterpart.

Comment: Yes, there isn't any one source that will meet all needs.  For minis you have to do a bit of searching, especially if you aren't interested in painting your own.

Answer (score 3):

As Rob said, [Otherworld](http://www.otherworld.me.uk/) minis is the best source if you want minis that are still in print. Their many miniatures EXACTLY replicate the images from the classic 1st edition Monster Manual. Particularly their giants, but also their hobgoblins, trolls and ogres will indeed kindle your nostalgia and are visually different from other choices on the market.

For OOP miniatures, I think Grenadier and Ral Partha minis from the late 70s and early 80s are best representative of the early TSR "style" and can be easily found on Ebay or other sources for used minis.

Comment: What's an 'OOP' miniature?

Comment: @Stewbob: OOP = "out of print".